# Returning view: undefined variable Laravel

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel

**ERORR Undefined variable: listings**

Users create a for sale advertising listing:

```
    $listing->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $listing->email= auth()->user()->email;
    $listing->phone_number= auth()->user()->phone_number;
    $listing->package = $request->session()->get('package');
    $listing->save();
    return view('user.dashboard');
```

After they get transferred to a dashboard page

```
@if($listings->isEmpty())
<div class="padding-top"> 
    <h1 class="centre">None</h1>
</div>
@else

@endif

@foreach ($listings as $listing)

<div class="row">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body row">
        <h5 class="card-title cardtitle col-lg-12 centre">{{$listing->address}}</h5>
```

incomplete html but just is an extract

**EDIT ADDED FULL CONTROLLER**  Using         return view('user.dashboard', ['listings' => $listing]); still throws an error

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'image1' => 'image|nullable|max:1999',
            'image2' => 'image|nullable|max:1999'
        ]);

        // Handle File Upload
        if($request->hasFile('image1')){
            // Get filename with the extension
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('image1')->getClientOriginalName();
            // Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get just ext
            $extension = $request->file('image1')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Filename to store
            $fileNameToStore= $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            // Upload Image
            $path = $request->file('image1')->storeAs('public/cover_images', $fileNameToStore);
        } else {
            $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
        }

        $listing = new Listings;
        $listing->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $listing->email= auth()->user()->email;
        $listing->phone_number= auth()->user()->phone_number;
        $listing->package = $request->session()->get('package');
        $listing->save();
        $listing->image1 = $fileNameToStore;
        return view('user.dashboard', ['listings' => $listing]);

}
```

Comment: __Nothing__ is passed to view in your code,

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `$listing` to your view like this:

```
return view('user.dashboard', compact('listing');
```

Edit:

Of course your variables must be named the same in your controller and view. You now have a mismatch as you name your variable `$listing` in your controller but call it as `$listings` in your view. Your code should be like this:

```
$listings->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
$listings->email= auth()->user()->email;
$listings->phone_number= auth()->user()->phone_number;
$listings->package = $request->session()->get('package');
$listings->save();
return view('user.dashboard', compact('listings');
```

Then you can call the variable as `$listings` in your view, so your view code doess not have to change.

EDIT 2:

`$listing` is ONE instance of the `Listings` model. So, you cannot call the `empty()` method on the object. I think you want to do something like this:

```
$listing = new Listings;
$listing->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
$listing->email= auth()->user()->email;
$listing->phone_number= auth()->user()->phone_number;
$listing->package = $request->session()->get('package');
$listing->save();
$listing->image1 = $fileNameToStore;
$listings = Listings::all();
return view('user.dashboard', compact('listings'));
```

Does this work out for you?

Ps. Do you want to set the `image1` attribute AFTER you save it? This will get lost.

Comment: Still getting Undefined variable: listings

Comment: Then you can do it like this: `return view('user.dashboard', ['listings' => $listing]);` But i would suggest you rename your variable in your controller from `$listing` to `$listings`.

Comment: Almost there getting Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::isEmpty does not exist. now

Comment: That is probably because you dont `get()` the result or something. We need the full method of your controller to see what is happening here. The variable `$listings` does not seem like a collection, so you are doing something else wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
return view('user.dashboard');
```

into

```
return view('user.dashboard', compact('listing'));
```

I think the reason is pretty clear.

Comment: Still getting Undefined variable: listings

Comment: Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::isEmpty does not exist. I am using return view('user.dashboard', ['listings' => $listing]);

Comment: You're really doing more than you show here because that error has nothing to do with both the posted code and my answer.

Comment: added full controller

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not importing model in the controller using namespace.
try to check using "Use auth" namespace

```
use App\Listing_Model;
use auth;

class DashboardController extends Controller {
    public function index() {


    $listing = new Listing_Model; 
    $listing->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $listing->email= auth()->user()->email;
    $listing->phone_number= auth()->user()->phone_number;
    $listing->package = $request->session()->get('package');
    $listing->save();
    return view('user.dashboard');

    }
}
```